# How to perform a function on table row click javascript/html

Tags: javascript, html

I have set up a table that returns Ajax results like so:

```
function searchUsers() {
    var searchText = (document.getElementById('searchInput').value)

    $.ajax({
    url : "https:" + "/" + "/downstreamaudio.com/SearchUsers.php",
    method : 'POST',
    data : {searchQuery: searchText},
    dataType: "json",
    success : function a(result) {
            console.log(result)

            console.log(result.length)

        var i;

        var table = document.getElementById("userSearchTableId");
        table.style.height = (result.length * 80 + "px")
        while(table.rows.length > 0) {
            table.deleteRow(0);
        }
    table.style.border = "0px solid black"

    for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
             console.log(result[i].username);

            document.querySelector('.userSearchTable').style.opacity = "100"

            var username = result[i].username;

            table.style.border = "4px solid black"

            table.style.borderCollapse = "seperate"

            var row = table.insertRow(0);

            row.onclick = cellClicked("Test");

            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            cell1.style.width = "80px"
            cell1.style.height = "50px"
            cell1.setAttribute("class", "UserImage")

            var image = document.createElement("img");
            image.height = "50"
            image.width = "50"
            image.style.backgroundColor = "green"
            image.style.margin = "15px 15px 15px 12px"
            image.style.padding = "0px 0px 0px 0px"
            image.style.borderRadius = "25px"
            image.style.borderColor = "black"
            image.style.border = "2px solid black"
            cell1.appendChild(image)

            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            cell2.style.fontSize = "20"
            cell2.style.fontFamily = "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"
            cell2.style.fontWeight = "Semi Bold"
            cell2.innerHTML = username


        }

    error : function b(jqxhr, status, exception) {
            alert(status);
    }

    }
})
```

Is it possible to make a row clickable so it calls a function onclick? I already tried adding `.onclick` to the row and that didn't work. I also need to know which row is being clicked as I need the innerHTML of a cell for that row.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table is written or created after page load, you need [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation). Set up the click listener on `document` then test for `tagName` to see if you're on a `TD`.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === "td") {
    let tr = e.target.closest('tr');
    console.log('found td tag with this contents: ', e.target.innerHTML)
    console.log('found tr tag with this contents: ', tr.innerHTML)
  } else {
    console.log('not a table cell', e.target.tagName)
  }
})

setTimeout(function() {
  document.querySelector('#content').innerHTML += "<table><tr><td>or me</td><td>or me too</td></tr></table>"
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div>try clicking me</div>

</div>
```